# Combining PhoneGap/Cordova with native views

Tags: cordova

I'm looking for example of how to combine native ui views in a phonegap/cordova project in either ios.  I like the phonegap approach but in particular, long lists can be a bit chunky on a web view, so i'd prefer to implement those directly with a native UITableView.  Ideally the UITableView click handler would pass the user off to a phonegap window.

I've been trolling around in the source code of the Cordova project but I figured if it scomes to that I'm probably overlooking something obvious.  I obviously could just hookup a UIWebView but then i'd be missing the javascript API hooks that PhoneGap/Cordova provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use Cordova as a component. This way, you can build a native application, and still have Cordova Webview and APIs. Check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Embedding Cordova WebView on Android ... and its works perfect ...

But in an other case I created native plugins instead of, in this way, the app is more simple